# UIPickerView iOS 11 scrolling and selection bug

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uipickerview, ios11

I have a problem with UIPickerView only in iOS 11.0.*, the picker view stops selecting items, and scroll incorrectly, it can scroll to empty places before the items, and after them, without calling the didSelectRow function, this happens only if I get in the screen then get out, then back in the screen again.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/axzzrxwfi12ng6n/ScreenRecording_10-25-2017%2014%3A19.m4v?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

After iOS update, it works on iOS 11.1...

Comment: unfortunately the problem still appear in iOS 11.1.*